# How to create listview dynamically using jquery mobile?

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using filter search like  [this](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html#/test/docs/lists/lists-search.html).But i have to create listview dynamically from database.pls help

Comment: is this when the page loads or are the links fetched via AJAX?

Comment: after page loads,i have to create search suggestion box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo Code:

```
$('#aboutPage').live('pagecreate',function(event){
    alert('This page was just loaded/enhanced by jQuery Mobile!');

    // do ajax call to get list
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourRequestPage.php?parm='+yourSearchParm[option],
        type: 'GET',
        error : function (){ document.title='error'; }, 
        success: function (data) {
            $('#selectOptionTag').html(data);

            // Something like this:
            $("div#selectOptionTag ul").listview();

            // Or this
            $('ul').listview('refresh');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the two cases you put there require different way of loading the data. first - data must contain the ul tag, second - ul tag can't be overwritten.

Comment: Hence the Pseudo Code. Not overwriting the ul tag appending li tags and refreshing via ajax call. Just trying to give the op a idea on how to go about doing this

Comment: Yes, I know. I did that a few times already and people said "no, it doesn't work" because they didn't fiddle with it, just put in their code and waited for it to work :P `pseudocode` doesn't work for most people ;)